# C program on sqlite db gives unable to open database file

Tags: c, database, sqlite

first of all I have to say that  this is not a duplicate thread due to another similar thread of mine related to this topic.
I wrote this simple sqlite C program for some tests but it does not close sqlite db with no error inside MySqlite_close function but after a while when it reached its maximum opened files it prints unable to open database file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sqlite3.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #define SQLITE_MAIN_BASE "/var/"
 #define SQLITE_DEVLOG_BASE  "./"
 #define Create_All_Database_Error 1
 MySqlite_close(sqlite3 *db)
 {
     int i=0,
         rc=0;
     rc=sqlite3_close(db);
     while(rc != SQLITE_OK)
     {
         printf("yet closing\n");
         if (rc == SQLITE_BUSY)
         {
             printf("it is busy\n");
             i++;
             if ( i > 10 )
             {
                 return rc;
             }
         }
         sleep(1);
         rc=sqlite3_close(db);
     }
     printf("2closeeeeeee\n\n");
     return 0;
 }
 int MySqlite_Exec(const char *dbname,sqlite3 *db,const char *query,sqlite3_stmt **retStmt,const char *queryTail2,const char *logpath,int logfd,int mode)
 {
     char logmessage[1500];
     char dbfilepath[150];
     int rc=0;
     sprintf(dbfilepath,"%s%s",SQLITE_DEVLOG_BASE,dbname);
     fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",query);
     while(sqlite3_open(dbfilepath, &db))
     {
         sprintf(logmessage,"1Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
         printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         sleep(10);

         MySqlite_close(db);
         return 0;
     }
     printf("10\n");
     if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, retStmt,NULL) != SQLITE_OK )
     {
         sprintf(logmessage,"2Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
         printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         while(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, retStmt,NULL) == SQLITE_BUSY)
         {
             sprintf(logmessage,"2Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
             printf("%s\n",logmessage);
             sleep(1);
         }
     }
     printf("12\n");
     if (mode==0)
     {
         printf("222\n");
         if (sqlite3_step(*retStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
         {
              sprintf(logmessage,"3Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
              printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         }
         if (sqlite3_reset(*retStmt) != SQLITE_OK)
         {
              sprintf(logmessage,"5Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
              printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         }

         if ( *retStmt != NULL )
         {
             printf("retStmt is not NULL\n");
             while(sqlite3_finalize(*retStmt)!=SQLITE_OK)
             {
                 sprintf(logmessage,"20Error on  : %u  %s ",sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                 printf("%s\n",logmessage);
                 printf("finilized NOT ok\n");
                 sleep(1);
             }
             printf("finilized ok\n");
             *retStmt=NULL;
         }
         else
         {
             printf("retStmt is NULL\n");
         }

         MySqlite_close(db);
    }
    return 0;
 }

 int Create_SqltDB(void)
 {
     char hostip[20],
          LOG_FILE[100],
          query[1000],
          dbfilepath[100],
          logmessage[1500];
     int result=0;
     const char *queryTail;
     sqlite3 *db;

     sqlite3_stmt *retStmt=NULL;
     sprintf(LOG_FILE,"/var/log/Emain.log");
     sprintf(query,"create table if not exists lastuptime(row integer primary key not NULL,microupdatetime double default 0 not NULL,time double default 0 not NULL);");
     if (MySqlite_Exec("lastuptime",db,query,&retStmt,queryTail,LOG_FILE,2,0))
     {
         return Create_All_Database_Error;
     }
     return 0;

 }
 int main()
 {
     sqlite3 *db;
     Create_SqltDB();
     char query[1000],
          logmessage[1500],
          LOG_FILE[100];
     int i=0,
         result=0;
     sqlite3_stmt *retStmt=NULL;
     const char *queryTail;
 /*    
     for (i=0; i<1100;i++)
     {
         sprintf(query,"insert into lastuptime(microupdatetime,time) values (%i,%i);",i,i);
         if (MySqlite_Exec("lastuptime",db,query,&retStmt,queryTail,LOG_FILE,2,0))
         {
             return Create_All_Database_Error;
         }
     }
 */
     while(1)
     {
         sprintf(query,"select * from lastuptime where row%%1000=0;");
         if (MySqlite_Exec("lastuptime",db,query,&retStmt,queryTail,LOG_FILE,2,1))
         {
             return Create_All_Database_Error;
         }

         do
         {
             result = sqlite3_step (retStmt) ;
             if (result == SQLITE_ROW) /* can read data */
             {
                 printf(" %d \t|\t %f \t|\t '%f' \n",\
                         sqlite3_column_int(retStmt,0),\
                         sqlite3_column_double(retStmt,1),\
                         sqlite3_column_double(retStmt,2)) ;
             }
             else
             {
                 printf("no data\n");
             }
         } while (result == SQLITE_ROW) ;
         printf("s1\n");
         MySqlite_close(db);
         printf("s2\n");
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

here is my sample output:

```
.
.
.
select * from lastuptime where row%1000=0;
10
12
1000 | 899.000000 | '899.000000' 
no data
s1
2closeeeeeee

s2
select * from lastuptime where row%1000=0;
10
12
1000 | 899.000000 | '899.000000' 
no data
s1
2closeeeeeee

s2
select * from lastuptime where row%1000=0;
1Error on "select * from lastuptime where row%1000=0;" : 14 unable to open database file 
2closeeeeeee

1000 | 899.000000 | '899.000000' 
no data
s1
2closeeeeeee

s2
select * from lastuptime where row%1000=0;
1Error on "select * from lastuptime where row%1000=0;" : 14 unable to open database file 
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is caused by the maximum number of file descriptors being reached? How do you infer that?

Comment: yes I am sure because no other process lock that and it always happen after a fixed number of opening db file and I saw that with : lsof -p `pidof MYPROCESSNAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution I had pointer problem . my whole changed code is as follow attention the change of db pointer in Mysqlite_exec function and other calls in other functions and I did not finalize my statment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sqlite3.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include "regex.c"
 #define SQLITE_MAIN_BASE "/var/"
 #define SQLITE_DEVLOG_BASE  "./"
 #define Create_All_Database_Error 1
 MySqlite_close(sqlite3 *db)
 {
     int i=0,
         rc=0;
     rc=sqlite3_close(db);
     while(rc != SQLITE_OK)
     {
         printf("yet closing\n");
         if (rc == SQLITE_BUSY)
         {
             printf("it is busy\n");
             i++;
             if ( i > 10 )
             {
                 return rc;
             }
         }
         sleep(1);
         rc=sqlite3_close(db);
     }
     printf("2closeeeeeee\n\n");
     return 0;
 }
 int Mysqlite_finalize(sqlite3 *db,sqlite3_stmt **retStmt)
 {
     char logmessage[1500];
 /*    if (sqlite3_reset(*retStmt) != SQLITE_OK)
     {
          sprintf(logmessage,"5Error is  : %u  %s ",sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
          printf("%s\n",logmessage);
     }
 */
     if ( *retStmt != NULL )
     {
         printf("retStmt is not NULL\n");
         while(sqlite3_finalize(*retStmt)!=SQLITE_OK)
         {
             sprintf(logmessage,"20Error on  : %u  %s ",sqlite3_errcode(db), sqlite3_errmsg(db));
             printf("%s\n",logmessage);
             printf("finilized NOT ok\n");
             sleep(1);
         }
         printf("finilized ok\n");
         *retStmt=NULL;
     }
     else
     {
         printf("retStmt is NULL\n");
     }
     return 0;

 }
 int MySqlite_Exec(const char *dbname,sqlite3 **db,const char *query,sqlite3_stmt **retStmt,const char *queryTail2,const char *logpath,int logfd)
 {
     char logmessage[1500];
     char dbfilepath[150];
     int rc=0;
     sprintf(dbfilepath,"%s%s",SQLITE_DEVLOG_BASE,dbname);
     fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",query);
     while(sqlite3_open(dbfilepath, db))
     {
         sprintf(logmessage,"1Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(*db), sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
         printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         sleep(10);

         MySqlite_close(*db);
         return 0;
     }
     printf("10\n");
     if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db, query, -1, retStmt,NULL) != SQLITE_OK )
     {
         sprintf(logmessage,"2Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(*db), sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
         printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         while(sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db, query, -1, retStmt,NULL) == SQLITE_BUSY)
         {
             sprintf(logmessage,"2Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(*db), sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
             printf("%s\n",logmessage);
             sleep(1);
         }
     }
     printf("12\n");
     if ( MyRegexMatch(query,"^select",REG_ICASE) !=0 )
     {
         printf("222\n");
         if (sqlite3_step(*retStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
         {
              sprintf(logmessage,"3Error on \"%s\" : %u  %s ",query,sqlite3_errcode(*db), sqlite3_errmsg(*db));
              printf("%s\n",logmessage);
         }
         Mysqlite_finalize(*db,retStmt);
         MySqlite_close(*db);
    }
    return 0;
 }

 int Create_SqltDB(void)
 {
     char hostip[20],
          LOG_FILE[100],
          query[1000],
          dbfilepath[100],
          logmessage[1500];
     int result=0;
     const char *queryTail;
     sqlite3 *db;

     sqlite3_stmt *retStmt=NULL;
     sprintf(LOG_FILE,"/var/log/Emain.log");
     sprintf(query,"create table if not exists lastuptime(row integer primary key not NULL,microupdatetime double default 0 not NULL,time double default 0 not NULL);");
     if (MySqlite_Exec("lastuptime",&db,query,&retStmt,queryTail,LOG_FILE,2))
     {
         return Create_All_Database_Error;
     }
     return 0;

 }
 int main()
 {
     sqlite3 *db;
     Create_SqltDB();
     char query[1000],
          logmessage[1500],
          LOG_FILE[100];
     int i=0,
         result=0;
     sqlite3_stmt *retStmt=NULL;
     const char *queryTail;

     for (i=0; i<100;i++)
     {
         sprintf(query,"insert into lastuptime(microupdatetime,time) values (%i,%i);",i,i);
         if (MySqlite_Exec("lastuptime",&db,query,&retStmt,queryTail,LOG_FILE,2))
         {
             return Create_All_Database_Error;
         }
     }

     while(1)
     {
         sprintf(query,"select * from lastuptime where row%%100=0;");

         if (MySqlite_Exec("lastuptime",&db,query,&retStmt,queryTail,LOG_FILE,2))
         {
             return Create_All_Database_Error;
         }

         while(sqlite3_step(retStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) /* can read data */
         {
              printf(" %d \t|\t %f \t|\t '%f' \n",\
                     sqlite3_column_int(retStmt,0),\
                     sqlite3_column_double(retStmt,1),\
                     sqlite3_column_double(retStmt,2)) ;
         }
         printf("s1\n");
         Mysqlite_finalize(db,&retStmt);
         MySqlite_close(db);
         printf("s2\n");
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `sqlite3_finalize`, so the database never gets closed.

Please note that [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) is for the latest SQLite version; yours might behave differently.